# Program not entering loop (Comparing two string values)

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, xcode

i am facing a weird problem i am simply comparing two string values and doing something if it matches .. i have created a Python script server from where i get one value and the other value is local string variable. i am able to retrive the proper value fromt the server but when comparing it does not enter the loop..

This is my code in my client to compare the values

```
-(void)messageReceived:(NSString *)message  {

    [_messages addObject:message];
    NSLog(@"the received message is %@",message);

    if (message == @"1") 
        NSLog(@"the user is online");
    else if (message == @"0") {
        UIAlertView *alert;
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"The selected user is not online !" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Here is a log that that i get showing the proper values

2012-02-25 21:44:35.376 iMessenger[2001:207] server said: 1
2012-02-25 21:44:35.377 iMessenger[2001:207] the received message is 1

can someone suggest me what is wrong .. Thanks

Comment: Your if statement is checking if the pointers are pointing to the same object. Working with Objective-C requires a pretty good understanding of pointers. See the answer by @sch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use == to compare strings. Use `[message isEqualToString:@"1"]` instead.

Comment: Do you mean `[message isEqualToString:@"1"]` does not evaluate to `YES` when message is `1`, and `NSLog(@"the user is online");` is not executed?

Comment: @Gaurav_soni - In the screenshot, there is a `\n`. That's a new line character. So `message` is `1\n` and not `1`. You should also correct `else if (message == @"0")`.

Comment: yea is saw that \n cant figure out how to remove that i am just sending 1 from the server side. should i post part of the server code?

Comment: Try to log the the message sent by the server. If you are not sure that it works correctly, may be that could be a separate question. Here, maybe you can add the code that receives the message and calls  `messageReceived`.

Comment: yea got it had to change the server script it was sending a next line that was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use *isEqualToString* to compare NSString values:

```
if ([message isEqualToString:@"1"])
    NSLog(@"the user is online");
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use caseInsensitiveCompare

```
if([message caseInsensitiveCompare:@"1"])
NSLog(@"the user is online");
```